# User-Place-Location database design solutuin

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, orm

I am bit confused how to design my database regarding relation.

1. I have User that could have many locations. (Tracking user location)
2. I have Place that could have many locations. (Place can be bar, restaurant, hospital... Place many locations - (For instance, McDonalds is a shack bar with many locations all around the world)

My confusion is relation between User--> Location and Place --> Location. I'm not sure If my thoughts are right.

- User can have many Location, but Location could have my users, restaurants.
- Place can be related with many Location, but Location can have more than one places (For instance, two bars in the same building have the same, lat,lng).

Is it correct to design database with ManyToMany relation both cases (User, Location) and (Place, Location)?

Comment: Can you give examples of what the data looks like?  For instance, what is a `location`?  A set of GPS coordinates, a name from an almanac, an approximation on a grid, or what?

Comment: Location is a set of lat,lng.

Comment: Assuming you cannot have two Places in the same Location, that is 1:many.

Comment: If Location is just lat+lng, then do not separate it into a different table.

Answer (score 0):

For many to many relationships, you should have a "table in the middle", that only references the primary keys of the related tables.  In your case, you have a table for `USERS` and `LOCATIONS`:

```
USERS:
pkUsers, userName, userPhone ... etc.

LOCATIONS:
pkLocation, street, city ... etc.
```

where `pkUsers` and `pkLocation` is the primary, autoincrement ID

The table in the middle should be something like `USERLOCATIONS` with two fields:

```
USERLOCATIONS
fkUsers, fkLocations
```

(where 'fk' represents foreign key)

Now, when location and user are linked, just add their primary keys into the table.

You can do the same for `RESTAURANTS` or any other table that is many to many.

Comment: Thanks! What about User-Location OneToMany relation? What would I lose if I go with this relation and not with ManyToMany ?

Comment: You can still have a one to many relationship in the two original fields, just like always.  This design is only necessary for a many to many.  So, in your table `USERS` you could have a field `fkTitle` which points to a person's title in the `TITLE` table (assuming users can only ever have one title).

Comment: If you feel this answered your question or was useful, please accept the answer and vote up.  Thank you!